# Auto generate XPath for known element in HTML tree using python

Tags: xpath, python-3.6, auto-generate

Is there any way (libs, not manually) for generating relative XPath for a known element in HTML?

Let say the second `P` element inside `class="content"`

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class"title">
            <h1>***</h1>
        </div>
        <p> *** </p>
        <h3>***</h3>
        <div class"content">
            <p>****</p>
            <p>****</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Use case:**
The idea is to guess where are the elements that I might be interested in. For example title, content or author. After I've found the element I want to generate xpath for it

Comment: I wrote couple of chrome extensions to generate the xpaths for the elements but this seems to be a special requirement where you want to get the xpath based on other element. I am sure it's going to be little tricky but it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
from lxml import etree

datum = """
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="title">
            <h1>***</h1>
        </div>
        <p> *** </p>
        <h3>***</h3>
        <div class="content">
            <p>something</p>
            <p>target</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
"""

root = etree.fromstring(datum)
tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
find_text = etree.XPath("//p[text()='target']")
for target in find_text(root):
    print(tree.getpath(target))
```

Output:

```
/html/body/div[2]/p[2]
```

Comment: Lxml was my first option, As you can see in the output the XPath is absolute, not relative 
it seems I have to build it my self something like this [Auto-generate XPaths using Python](https://qxf2.com/blog/auto-generate-xpaths-using-python/)